# Groovy File.getText() - Do I have to close something?

Tags: file, groovy, filereader

If I use the `File.getText()` method in groovy

`newFile().text` or `newFile().getText()`

do I have to execute some closure statements to close the used file reader or will the method do it by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will do it by itself.

Calling `new File( 'a.txt' ).text` [will call](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.java#L583) `ResourceGroovyMethods.getText( File )`

```
public static String getText(File file, String charset) throws IOException {
    return IOGroovyMethods.getText(newReader(file, charset));
}
```

Which as you can see [calls](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L856) `IOGroovyMethods.getText( BufferedReader )`:

```
public static String getText(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    // reading the content of the file within a char buffer
    // allow to keep the correct line endings
    char[] charBuffer = new char[8192];
    int nbCharRead /* = 0*/;
    try {
        while ((nbCharRead = reader.read(charBuffer)) != -1) {
            // appends buffer
            answer.append(charBuffer, 0, nbCharRead);
        }
        Reader temp = reader;
        reader = null;
        temp.close();
    } finally {
        closeWithWarning(reader);
    }
    return answer.toString();
}
```

Which as you can see, closes the Reader when done